# Why am I unable to assign to a particular element in a list of lists

Tags: python

I don't understand why I am assigning to the first element in every list below:

```
➜  ~  python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> board = [[None]*5]*5
>>> print board
[[None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None]]
>>> board[0][0] = 1
>>> print board
[[1, None, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None, None], [1, None, None, None, None]]
```

I would expect the final output to be this:

```
[[1, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Comment: That's because all lists `[None, None, None, None, None]` are copies of same object, modifying one modifies all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this one:

```
x = [None]*5
board = [x for i in range(5)]
```

If you want 5 different lists, do it:

```
board = [[None]*5 for i in range(5)]
```